# Static Address vs. Execution Address In An Elf Loader

Tags: linker, arm, elf, arm64, relocation

I am writing an Elf Loader for ARM/ARM64. While processing the dynamic relocations I became a bit confused by some of the terms/symbols in the [documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0056b/IHI0056B_aaelf64.pdf) I am following. 
On Pg.14 it is stated,

"S (when used on its own) is the address of the symbol."
"P is the address of the place being relocated (derived from r_offset)."

"Delta(S) if S is a normal symbol, resolves to the difference between the static link address of S and the
execution address of S. If S is the null symbol (ELF symbol index 0), resolves to the difference between the
static link address of P and the execution address of P."

From what I gather, I believe the "execution address" of S (or P) to be the address of the symbol in the process's memory space but am unsure what is meant by "static link address".

If someone can clarify the terminology that would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is meant by "static link address".

A non-PIE executable is linked to load at a particular address. For example, on `x86_64` Linux default static link address is `0x400000`:

```
echo "int main() { return 0; }" | gcc -xc - -no-pie

readelf -Wl a.out | grep LOAD
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x000618 0x000618 R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x000e50 0x0000000000600e50 0x0000000000600e50 0x0001d8 0x0001e0 RW  0x200000
```

This binary is linked with static link address of `0x400000`, and symbols in it reflect that:

```
nm a.out | grep ' main'
0000000000400487 T main
```

This executable *must* be loaded at `0x400000`, and will not work correctly if loaded anywhere else.

Note that default non-PIE static link address

- is different for different architectures (`i386` default is `0x8048000`), and
- can be changed at static link time via linker script and/or linker flags.

Contrast this with a PIE executable, which is typically linked at static link address `0`:

```
echo "int main() { return 0; }" | gcc -xc - -fPIE -pie
 readelf -Wl a.out | grep LOAD
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0007d8 0x0007d8 R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x000e18 0x0000000000200e18 0x0000000000200e18 0x000210 0x000218 RW  0x200000

nm a.out | grep ' main'
00000000000005fa T main
```

So the static link address of `main` is `0x400487` in the non-PIE case, and `0x5fa` in the PIE case.